# Keep a database synced with Google Drive spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, google-drive-api

I am making a rails system that can be managed by editing a Google spreadsheet that holds data in a specific form (note: that form is NOT the same format as any database table).

I want multiple tables in my (postgresql) database to be updated upon changes to the spreadsheet, and I also want changes to the database to be reflected in the spreadsheet. The latter is easy to do; I can simply use the `google-drive` gem to change the cells that I want to change.

My question is: how can I "listen" for changes to the google doc itself? Does it require polling for changes every few seconds? Or can the Drive API be used to fire events to my server?

Polling is definitely possible, but I believe it would require a worker dyno (I'm using heroku), which isn't really desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Chech the drive api docs on how to listen for changes. You can listen to sn dngire drive or specific files change.
If you want something more fine-grained than 'i changed' you could use an apps script and add onEdit/onChange triggers which give you more detailed info about what changed. From the script you can notify your server with urlFetchApp.